# GWT - Vertical border line divides panel on two parts

Tags: gwt

Does anyone know how to make, in GWT, panel which has a vertical boundary line that divides the panel on two parts same like this http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html ?

I want when click on the blue border line to hide/show left menu same as on the above link.

I can't to find any example of that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your boy : http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalSplitPanel.html

You can configure the handler of the bar so that it does what you want.